# How to include early access field in IEEE bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

When a paper is early accessed in IEEE library, how can I cite it and add the note "early access" in the IEEE bibliography? Thank you!

Comment: You can just use the `note` field to add such information, alternatively you may use the `addendum` field; bot bfields are supported by the majority of BibTeX and `biblatex` styles. If you use `biblatex` there is also `pubstate` you can choose one of the keywords provided by `biblatex` (see p. 216 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) or type in what you think is appropriate.

Comment: I use IEEETran bibliographystyle, but only adding note field works.

Comment: Yes, the IEEEtran bib style does only support `note` of the fields I have listed above. When you said "IEEE bibliography" I wasn't to sure what package/tool you use to get the bibliography, especially because you also tagged your question `biblatex`. I will remove that tag then, since you don't use `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use bibtex but just IEEEtran bib style only support note.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `note` or `addendum` field to add information such as this. I think the `note` field is slightly more prevalent than addendum. In some styles there are also `howpublished` and `pubstate` which could be appropriate here.